# jQuery - What's the most efficient way to filter out first and second elements found?

Tags: jquery

I am using the latest and greatest jQuery.

I will have a ten divs with content. On page load, I need to close all divs except the first and second.  Only the first two divs I want visible.

Under those visible two divs are "show more" and "show less" buttons. When the user clicks the show more button, all divs will slide down. When the user clicks the show less button, all but the first two divs should slide up.

I know how to get at the first, the last, but I don't know how to filter out the first and the second element. I know I could get this done with more tinkering than I have already done, but I want to know the most efficient and readable way of getting it done.  Can you help me?

One page load, this should go through and close all but the first and second divs:

```
$(".BrandParagraph").each(function() {
    // should close all but first and second
    $(this).slideUp;
});

 $(".ShowMore").click(function() {
     // slide down all
     $(".BrandParagraph").slideDown();
 });

 $(".ShowMore").click(function() {
     // slide up all but first and second
     $(".BrandParagraph").slideDown();
 });
```

Comment: .eq(i) will treat the list of elements returned as an array an let you get the elements you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use gt(n) to select elements greater than the index n:

```
$(".myDivs:gt(1)")
```

Comment: Yes, this one worked absolutely perfectly and used the least amount of code, and is very readable.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try using the greather than index selector:   [jQuery :gt(n)](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$(".BrandParagraph:gt(1)")
```

You would modify your code to this:

```
$(".BrandParagraph:gt(1)").each(function() {
    // should close all but first and second
    $(this).slideUp;
});

 $(".ShowMore").click(function() {
     // slide down all
     $(".BrandParagraph").slideDown();
 });

 $(".ShowLess").click(function() {
     // slide up all but first and second
     $(".BrandParagraph:gt(1)").slideDown();
 });
```

Comment: and this is why i didn't post my comment as an answer... :) knew someone had something better :-p +1

Comment: @kralco626 that's no good :P you can post your answer anyway and if you really want to, you can delete it in favor of another, but don't let it stop you from providing input to the community.

Comment: You don't need `each` in the first line - you can just call `slideUp()` on the selection.

Comment: @joe - There are already two distinct other solutions better than mine, and multiple people already posted my solution. Plus he said most efficient, and I have no idea which was is most efficient... :-p that being said... your right

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `slice` method to get all items but the two first:

```
$(".BrandParagraph").slice(2).slideUp();
```

Comment: Very nice, I like this because it can take a second parameter as the end... http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're over complicating the problem... just add a class to those first to divs and select off of that.  If your bent on selecting only the first and second, the syntax is `$(selector).eq(0)` and `$(selector).eq(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? Seems simplistic but it should get the job done...

```
    var divCount = 1;

    $(".BrandParagraph").each(function() {
    if(divCount >2){
    // should close all but first and second
    $(this).slideUp;
}
else
{
  divCount++;
}
});

 $(".ShowMore").click(function() {
     // slide down all
     $(".BrandParagraph").slideDown();
 });

 $(".ShowMore").click(function() {
     // slide up all but first and second
     $(".BrandParagraph").slideDown();
 });
```

Comment: This is the solution that I would have come up with and wanted to avoid. The other answers on the page are super slick. Check 'em out. Thanks for your answer though.